# Magento version 1.9.1.0 Database Issue

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9.1

I have developed a website on Magento version 1.9.1.0 and getting an issue of the duplicate entry in database table "report_viewed_product_index". 
I have checked database table and found in this table no foreign key constraints define but in SQL setup they have foreign keys for this table.

After this, we have checked the database of Magento version 1.9.0.1 and they also have same SQL setup for this table and also define foreign keys under this table.

Without foreign key the table not updated automatically. so it will generate duplicate entry error for product report. and give 404 page not found an error on product detail page after login customer.

How can I solve this issue?

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_STORE` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `{$installer->getTable('core/store')}` (`store_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_CUSTOMER` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `{$installer->getTable('customer/entity')}` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRODUCT` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `{$installer->getTable('catalog/product')}` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: By adding the foreign keys?

Comment: @Shadow - but we have also checked Magento new versions it will also work without a foreign key. if I will add foreign key then are you sure Magento website is working fine?

Comment: You need to confirm that through your own testing.